# VBA Save to SharePoint Method SaveAs failed

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to save a file to SharePoint via the Macro Below.  I have another file that uses this exact script and executes perfectly.  But, this method presents "Run time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed ".  If I copy and past the URL I go to the correct location which makes me think the URL is not the issue.

```
    Sub Save_To_SharePoint()
Dim wbName As String

ActiveWorkbook.Save

wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        "sharepoint url" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

MsgBox ("Workbook has been saved to SharePoint.  This workbook will now close.")

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Even though the URL seems to work in a browser, does not mean it is the correct format in a macro. In the past I have had to swap out forward slashes for back slashes and vice versa, so give that a go first. You may also have access issues with Sharepoint where you need a sign-on to access the relevant folder. For example: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-saving-a-workbook-in-a-sharepoint-directory.1113762/

Comment: "sharing" or "open"/"view" SharePoint links may often be formatted differently from what you'd want as a "save" path.  You may need to clean up or reformat the URL you're using.